# Isometries and complex differentials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assume that A is a linear operator of $L^2(D)$ onto istelf, where $D$ is the unit disk. Assume that $f\to \partial A[f](z)$ and $f\to \bar \partial A[f ](z)$ are isometries. Whether it implies that $A$ is a contraction?

Comment: Just a suggestion, but I think you might want to think about what you're taking as the codomains of $\partial$ and $\bar \partial$, and in what sense you want to be taking derivatives (assuming that's what $\partial$ and $\bar \partial$ stand for that is).